# Intel Pentium T3200 - Memory configuration

Tags: memory, cpu, intel-pentium

.Hi! Today I was repairing friends laptop and I did it, but he asked me about upgrading his RAM. He has 2x 2GB ddr2 RAMS and the CPU is 64bit, but I cannot find possible RAM configs for the CPU mentioned in the title. Can anyone tell me if 8GB will work and how to find that info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the model of the laptop, I went searching for a Acer Aspire with that processor which corresponds to a [5735Z](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/acer-aspire-5735z-review/).

Looking through the [manual](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf/1/100/9986-acer/5335.pdf?55cdfb69998d3afaec9241c79bc8bbee) I found out that this laptop only supports up to a maximum of 4GB of DDR2 667mhz of RAM (2x2GB setup as mentioned in the image), therefore , it's not possible an upgrade to 8GB:

[image]